# Call to Gmail API Update method is not generating an result or an error

Tags: c#, gmail-api

So, i'm calling the method to update the primary "sendAs" object of a google account, without results. The documentation from google at [users.settings.sendAs/update](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.settings.sendAs/update?hl=pt-br) indicates all i need and did:

1. i've set the domain wide account and scopes
2. i'm generating a token and accessing it no problem
3. i'm calling the "list" method first (with that token) as shown in [users.settings.sendAs/list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.settings.sendAs/list?hl=pt-br) documentation, and finding the one that is the primary (the "isPrimary" attribute is true)

After that, changing the "signature" value to "Its a Test Signature", and sending the PUT request with it doesn't do anything.

The JSON sent to the update API (via PUT method) is the exact one i collected from the list (the primary one), but with the signature changed.

There is no error at all, and i receive an "sendAs" object back as a response (as the documentation says i should in case of sucess), but the signature is unchanged.

What can i be?

**EDIT (adding the code section for the call, again - no errors)**

```
public bool Update()
{
    string json = null;
    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
        wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
        wc.Headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + GenerateServerToServerToken(this.OwnerMail, this.scope);
        json = wc.DownloadString("https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/" + this.OwnerMail + "/settings/sendAs");
        JSon.Query response = JSon.Parse(ref json);
        json = null;
        response = response["sendAs"];
        List<JSon.Query> mailAs = null;
        if (response.TryParseList(out mailAs))
        {
            JSon.Query main = null;
            bool prim = false;
            foreach (JSon.Query q in mailAs)
            {
                if (q["isPrimary"].TryParseBoolean(out prim) && prim)
                {
                    if (q["sendAsEmail"].TryParseString(out json)) { main = q; }
                    break;
                } else { json = null; }
            }
            if (main != null)
            {
                JSon.ObjectValue mainO = (JSon.ObjectValue)main.Value;
                if (mainO.ContainsKey("signature"))
                {
                    ((JSon.StringValue)mainO["signature"]).Data = this.HtmlSignature.Replace("<", ("\\" + "u003c")).Replace(">", ("\\" + "u003e"));
                    mainO["verificationStatus"] = new MdIO.JSon.StringValue("accepted");
                    json = wc.UploadString("https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/" + this.OwnerMail + "/settings/sendAs/" + json, "PUT", main.Value.ToJSON());
                    response = JSon.Parse(ref json);
                    if (response["sendAsEmail"].TryParseString(out json) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(json)) { return true; }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What is the FROM address in the email you receive?  All the SendAs does is change From Address of the Email.

Comment: please edit your question and include [example]

Comment: DalmTo, i'll post some of the code, but to reproduce it needs the google key (that i canot share) - just i get no error at all, so i don't have an stack trace to publish the error

Comment: jdweng, not according to documentation (and examples on google developers channel on youtube) - in fact, they give an example (that generated my code) to do just that - change signature at primary

Comment: resolved: instead of PUT should be PATCH (on the httpmethod) and for some reason, the WebClient request/response is an problem for that method, so a HttpWebResquest and GetResponse approach replaces that as well, then it all works.